# Find the number of ways of inviting $9$ friends

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

A man has $9$ friends , $4$ boys and $5$ girls. In how many ways he can invite them such that there is atleast 1 girl among the invitees.

My approach:
1 girl can be selected in 5 ways for remaining 8 people they can be invited in $2^{8}$ ways.
So total number of ways to invite firneds=$5*2^8$=1280. Is this correct? If not could you please point out the mistakes. Thank you

Comment: You have a lot of over counting.  You count both the cases where Alice is the first girl picked and Betty is also picked as well as the cases where Betty is the first girl picked and Alice is also picked, but these are the same cases.  It's best to do it as Lion Heart has shown in his answer: the number of possibilities minus the number of possibilities with no girls.

Comment: @saulspatz is it akin to number of ways of selecting boys= $2^{4}$ and number of ways of selecting women=$2^{5}-1$  so final result will be the product of these two?

Comment: That's another good way of looking at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $9$ people there are $2^9$ different selections.

And for $4$ boys there are $2^4$ different selections

If it will be at least one girl in the group, the number of different selections is $2^9-2^4=496$

Comment: Thank you so much!!